# Accidentally deleted the / etc folder

Tags: data-recovery

After 11 year in Linux... i accidentally managed to delete the /etc folder.

I was cleaning up a different hard drive from another machine. Thus 
Instead of :
    $ user@machine: /media/mount/newdrive > sudo rm -Rf etc

I did
    $ user@machine: /media/mount/newdrive > sudo rm -Rf /etc

Now I use netrunner based on arch.

How can I recover my system the fastest?

I have /home /opt and / boot separately mounted.

I know that running the live media is an option but this will redo my /bin

Any better options... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you did a custom install with /home and / on different mount points. You will have to start from scratch or start a live cd and run a hard drive recovery program to recover the /etc folder.
Hopefully you have backups. :)

Comment: I have  /home And / on separate partitions. But how will this help? I'm still losing my /Bin- am I not? And I am.not sure one can recover missing data on Linux that easily...no I do not have back up of the / etc folder

Comment: @Sean `/bin` and `/etc` are two separate directories. Your best option is a full reinstallation because `/etc` contains virtually all of your config files including the ones for the libraries, the system's hostname, and logging as well as the access and sudo information and the system's shell init files and user and group databases and that's just getting started. You can boot into a Live USB/CD like this answer suggests but it won't have any config files for packages that you installed after installing the system itself or for anything that you've changed.

Comment: Of course they are..I was just wondering if I can reinstall my system without destroying the previously installed binaries